# Calling a script whenever enter is hit

Tags: bash

How do you get bash to call a (bash) script every time someone hits enter?

I want the prompt to change every time it is displayed.

Comment: The subject is merely that. The body is intended to contain a question and any necessary contextual information. Get rid of your meta commentary and explain what it is that you are trying to do, and what you've tried so far. What errors have you encountered?

Comment: @Mat: Thank you for changing my question. This is exactly how i tried to submit it originally but it would not let me because it "doesn't meet the quality standards".

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the bash man page for PROMPT_COMMAND. It sounds like you will want to set the value of PS1 in whatever function you set PROMPT_COMMAND to.